# how to convert CR2 to jpg in batches on digital photo professional 4.1

Tags: raw, jpeg, batch

how to convert a batch of CR2 to jpg on digital photo professional 4.1

Step by step please.

Comment: Maybe start with File> Convert and Save?

Comment: It's all in the *Instructions*. http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300015460/01/dpp-4-0-00-w-im-en.pdf

Answer (score 6):

1. Within Digital Photo Professional navigate to the folder
   containing your CR2 files. From the top menu click File > Batch
   Process...
2. The "Batch settings" window will open.
3. To choose where the output jpeg files will be saved click the "Browse..." button in the "Save folder" section. The "Browse For Folder" window will open, click the desired output folder to select it then click the "OK" button.
4. In the next section down "File format" select "Exif-JPEG" from the "Kind of file" drop down. Drag the "Image quality" slider slider all the way to the right (10).
5. In the next section down "Output setting" type "300" into the "Output resolution" text box. Ensure that the "Embed ICC profile" tick box has a tick in it.
6. In the next section down "Resize setting" ensure that the "Resize" tick box does not have a tick in it.
7. In the next section down "File name" click "Current file name", and delete any text in the "String" text box.
8. Click the Execute button at the bottom to perform the batch conversion.

The above steps will result in JPEG copies of your RAW files being saved in the output directory with the same file names and pixel dimensions as the original RAW files. The image quality is set to 10 so the compression applied will be minimal.

Comment: @AJ Henderson impersonator?

Comment: @dpollitt, nope :)
Though he does seem quite accomplished, so a role model perhaps.

Comment: Once I have converted them to JPEG. Where exactly do they go? I know you said output directory but im not sure where that is located.

Comment: @user47411 They went to the folder you designated in step 3 of the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

One very important part missing from this answer to those less able.
On the left of the main image is a column of images within the folder selected.
Unless you select all of these only the first file will be processed.
ie the batch process does not do its job you have to help it.
You can do this two ways either once the folder you want is selected go to, file-select all
Or click the top most photo in the column and then scroll to the end and while holding the shift key click the last photo.
Or if you only need certain photos, click each one while holding the ctrl key once you have what you want selected then carry on the batch process.